# How can I enable the input if the two ajax functions check that there is no email and the user

Tags: php, jquery, database

I have a form checking real-time username and email.

```
     $('#email').blur(function() {
        $th = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email: $th.val()},
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultEmail").html("* "+data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#error").html("Error");
            }
         });//ajax 1
    })

    $('#username').blur(function() {
        $th = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {username: $th.val()},
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultUser").html("* "+data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#error").html("Error");
            }
         });//ajax 2
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" class="input-field"/>
   <label for="username" class="label-field">Username <div id="resultUser">*</div></label>
</div>

<div class="input">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-field" required="required"/>
   <label for="email" class="label-field">E-mail <div id="resultEmail">*</div></label>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled />
```

How can I make the input be enabled if the requests verify that the username and the email do not exist in the database

in `check.php` page if there is email or username print

```
    $rows = $query->num_rows;

    if($rows>0){
        echo "exists in DB";
    }
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, you should look at using `Deferred` objects to achieve this. Specifically, if you want to have two separate `AJAX` requests that you only act upon when both are complete/successful, the `.when()` method allows this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: I would suggest you do all the checking during submit of the form. That way is more user friendly in my opinion.